# Conditional row drop in pandas affects previously defined dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

came across an issue in python coding today. I was trying to conditionally drop some rows from a data frame. Basically, I wanted to create a copy of my data frame so I could see which rows had been dropped by comparing the copied dataframe with the dataframe that I dropped the rows from. Here is a simplified example in code:

```
import pandas as pd
# define simple data frame
d = {'col1': ['chris', 'ben'], 'col2': [3, 8]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# define df2 to be identical to df AS CURRENTLY DEFINED
df2=df
# next, drop all rows in df if 'col1' = 'ben'
df.drop(df.loc[df['col1']=='ben'].index, inplace=True)
```

What I'm really puzzled by is that, when executed line by line, even though the last line of code only makes reference to df, **it performs that operation on df2 as well**!

Why is this? Is there something I'm completely missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `d2=df.copy()` instead of `d2=df` to create a copy